# What Are Disconnected Diagrams?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I started studying Peskin & Schroeder on my own and I am having a really hard time understanding what exactly are disconnected diagrams? How do they appear and what terms do we assign to them.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just understood what that means. Consider a term like this:

$$T[\phi(x)\phi(y) (\frac{-i \lambda}{4!}) \int{d^4z \phi(z)\phi(z)\phi(z)\phi(z)} ]$$

The terms where $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ are contracted give external points and hence *connected* diagrams. *Disconnected* diagrams come from the terms where neither $\phi(x)$ nor $\phi(y)$ are contracted.

Comment: Not sure if you got it right. I'd propose to draw some example diagrams and write down the corresponding time ordered products with contractions to see what is going on.

Comment: I have. I am surprised that you are not sure about that.

Comment: For example, if you contract $\phi(x)$ with $\phi(y)$ and $\phi(z)$ with $\phi(z)$, then both $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ are contracted but the diagram which you will get won't be connected (you will have a propagator from $x$ to $y$ and a loop bubble at $z$ which is disconnected from the propagator.

Comment: Oh I see the confusion, OK you’re right I did not express myself right. Thank you very much. I will edit my explanation.